# How to find time difference in datetime records of the same day using Lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Here is a table which contains multiple events for user activity along with the date and time the activity is performed. How do I find time difference in between in between each of the pair activities.

`Activity | Datetime`

`IN       |2019-11-12 06:45:14.1234042`

`OUT      |2019-11-12 09:20:14.2291323`

`IN       |2019-11-12 10:35:14.4541043`

`OUT      |2019-11-12 19:36:14.3431042`

`IN       |2019-11-13 09:33:14.6541045`

`OUT      |2019-11-13 18:35:14.3441042`

`IN       |2019-11-14 06:32:14.2361042`

`OUT      |2019-11-14 12:23:14.2345044`

`IN       |2019-11-14 16:24:14.3791034`

`IN       |2019-11-15 11:10:14.2245446`

`OUT      |2019-11-15 19:44:14.5349504`

The caveat, is there can be missing pared action look at 2019/11/14 where there is no Out entry for the second In entry. In that case the In  entry is considered void.

The output would look like

`2019-11-12 | 02:35`

`2019-11-12 | 09:01`

`2019-11-13 | 09:02`

`2019-11-14 | 05:51`

`2019-11-15 | 04:01`

`2019-11-16 | 08:34`

Comment: A few hints. 1) to convert a string to a DateTime, you can use the static `Parse`, `ParseExact` or better `TryParseExact` methods of the DateTime class, and 2) if you subtract a DateTime from another DateTime, you get a TimeSpan

Answer (score 1):

I may have gone overkill on this LOL! But I started writing it, so I may as well post it. By the way, I wrote this in Notepad++ and haven't tried to run it in Visual Studio, so I can't promise it will work right away.

The general idea though is that you have to load the data, then you have to pair up your groups according to the particular rules you need. Then you can use Linq to get the time spans between the INs and OUTs pairs.

```
namespace SODemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Load the data
            List<ActivityTime> activities = ReadInActivityTimes();

            //Trying to do a lambda on the activities list would be out of scope
            // for a normal use of a Linq query. Because each item requires knowledge of the
            // next item in the list. So there needs to be a step where the related pairs are grouped.
            List<ActivityTimePair> pairs = CreatePairs(activities);

            //Now we can run a Linq query. 
            List<TimeSpan> output = pairs
                .Where(p => p.HasBoth)
                .Select(p => p.GetTimeSpan().Value)
                .ToList();

            output.ForEach(ts => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString());
            });
        }

        static List<ActivityTime> ReadInActivityTimes()
        {
            return new List<ActivityTime>() {
                new ActivityTime() { Activity = "IN", TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("2019-11-12 06:45:14.1234042" },
                new ActivityTime() { Activity = "OUT", TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("2019-11-12 09:20:14.2291323" },
                new ActivityTime() { Activity = "IN", TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("2019-11-12 10:35:14.4541043" },
                new ActivityTime() { Activity = "OUT", TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("2019-11-12 19:36:14.3431042" },
                new ActivityTime() { Activity = "IN", TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("2019-11-13 09:33:14.6541045" },
                new ActivityTime() { Activity = "OUT", TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("2019-11-13 18:35:14.3441042" },
                new ActivityTime() { Activity = "IN", TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("2019-11-14 06:32:14.2361042" },
                new ActivityTime() { Activity = "OUT", TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("2019-11-14 12:23:14.2345044" },
                new ActivityTime() { Activity = "IN", TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("2019-11-14 16:24:14.3791034" },
                new ActivityTime() { Activity = "IN", TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("2019-11-15 11:10:14.2245446" },
                new ActivityTime() { Activity = "OUT", TimeStamp = DateTime.Parse("2019-11-15 19:44:14.5349504" }
            };
        }

        static List<ActivityTimePair> CreatePairs(List<ActivityTime> activities)
        {
            List<ActivityTimePair> pairs = new List<ActivityTimePair>();

            for (int i = 0; i < activities.Count; i++)
            {
                if (pairs.Count == 0) //first one
                {
                    pairs.Add(new ActivityTimePair());
                }

                if (activities[i].Activity == "IN")
                {
                    //If the last pair has an OUT, then we need a new pair
                    if (pairs.Last().OUT != null)
                    {
                        pairs.Add(new ActivityTimePair() { IN = activities[i]});
                    }
                    //handle case where there are 2 IN's in a row
                    else if (pairs.Last().IN != null) 
                    {
                        //Means there is 2 INs in a row
                        pairs.Add(new ActivityTimePair() { IN = activities[i]});
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        pairs.Last().IN = activities[i];
                    }
                }

                if (activities[i].Activity == "OUT")
                {
                    //If the last pair has an OUT, there are 2 OUT's in a row
                    if (pairs.Last().OUT != null)
                    {
                        //Means there is 2 OUTs in a row
                        pairs.Add(new ActivityTimePair() { OUT = activities[i]});
                    }
                    else if (pairs.Last().IN != null) 
                    {
                        pairs.Last().OUT = activities[i];
                    }
                    //handle case where we need a new pair
                    else 
                    {
                        pairs.Add(new ActivityTimePair() { OUT = activities[i]});
                    }
                }
            }

            return pairs;
        }
    }

    class ActivityTime
    {
        public string Activity { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    }

    class ActivityTimePair
    {
        public ActivityTime IN { get; set; }
        public ActivityTime OUT { get; set; }

        public bool HasBoth 
        {
            get
            {
                return IN != null && OUT != null;
            }
        }

        public TimeSpan? GetTimeSpan()
        {
            if (HasBoth)
            {
                return OUT.TimeStamp.Subtract(IN.TimeStamp);
            }
            else 
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that using `Lambda` expression is the best solution here. According to your requirements you need to skip orphan `INs` and this is additional level of complexity that may require additional searches through your list. It will be much more efficient to have single loop with logic inside that will just compare current and next element:

```
var list = new List<Activity>
{
    new Activity { Type = "IN", Date = DateTime.Now },
    new Activity { Type = "OUT", Date = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(15) },
    new Activity { Type = "IN", Date = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(23) },
    new Activity { Type = "OUT", Date = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(27) }
};

var result = new List<string>();
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
{
    var current = list[i];
    var next = list[i+1];
    if (current.Type == "OUT" || current.Type == next.Type)
    {
        continue;
    }

    var duration = next.Date - current.Date;
    result.Add($"{current.Date:yyyy-MM-dd} | {duration.Minutes:00}:{duration.Seconds:00}");
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, wont be only using Lambda but in combination with other logic. Thank you